# How can I customize/extend a react-native Animation?

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native, react-animated

I want to create a custom decay animation, that stops when a specific check returns true.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
this.decayAnimation = decay(
    this.state.animatedXYValue,
    {
      velocity: { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 },
      deceleration: 0.996,
    }
);
this.decayAnimation.start();
```

But I want to stop animating, (or change the deceleration) if the x or y value

(not the velocity, but the actual x or y value of `this.state.animatedXYValue : AnimatedValueXY`)

becomes bigger than let's say 500.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thank you.